# Why is this UnhandledException event handler not working?

Tags: c#, uncaughtexceptionhandler

Not able to execute code after exception, it is printing

> ccccc

but does not print

> AFTER_EXCEPTION

The code is showing the caught exception and then exists.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{      
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler); // using System.Diagnostics;

    //   Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(OnThreadException);

    Process p = Process.GetProcessById(1000);

    Console.WriteLine("AFTER_EXCEPTION");

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("cccc");

    Exception temp = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + temp.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + temp.TargetSite);           
}
```

Comment: where are you getting an exception?

Comment: Added sentence to show part of code. Please provide your question in detail

Comment: This is now a very poor question, you have provided no detail

Answer (score -1):

It's all good to setup a global Exception handler, but you still need to use the C# mechanics, try...catch.

If it throws an exception and the global handler catches it, it won't resume at the point of the exception because it doesn't know how to.

The clue is therefore in the name, it's for unhandled exceptions (that aren't caught), and is normally used for logging and graceful cleardown, not a C# equivalent of Visual Basics Resume on Error mechanic.

Comment: NB: This answer is based on the assumption I get from reading your code, you should really add some detail explain your reasoning and your expectations from this code.